# argument list in Function pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, gcc, posix

I can print more than 2 arguments in my function ptr   * Os_printf *
  but my function only works with 1 argument.

for example -->

```
Os_printf("Moon %d %d",55,5);
```

OUT:

> Moon 55 5

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char db[50];

void test_1(int (*debug)())
{
    debug("JOY %d %d \n",4,55);
}

volatile int (*ptr_fscreener)(char * __restrict, const char * __restrict, ...);

void Os_formater(int (*debug)() )
{
  ptr_fscreener=debug;
}

void Os_printf(const char  * __restrict out,void**d)
{
va_list args;
char db[50];
ptr_fscreener(db,out,d);
puts(db);
}

int main(void) {
    Os_formater(sprintf);
    Os_printf("Moon %d",55);
    test_1(printf);
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }


/*******  OUTPUT For example  ******/
       Moon 55
       JOY 4 55
       !!!Hello World!!!
```

Comment: If you're asking "how do I make my own variadic functions?", the answer is pretty simple: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html, but your wording is a statement, not a question, so it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `<stdarg.h>` and probably `vsnprintf()`, amongst numerous other changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void test_1(int (*debug)(const char *format, ...))
{
    debug("JOY %d %d\n",4,55);
}

static int (*ptr_fscreener)(char *, size_t, const char *, va_list);

void Os_formatter(int (*debug)(char *buffer, size_t buflen, const char *format, va_list args))
{
    ptr_fscreener = debug;
}

void Os_printf(const char *out, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char db[50];
    va_start(args, out);
    ptr_fscreener(db, sizeof(db), out, args);
    va_end(args);
    puts(db);
}

int main(void)
{
    Os_formatter(vsnprintf);
    Os_printf("Moon %d",55);
    test_1(printf);
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Using `vsnprintf()` gives you some protection against buffer overflow as long as you use it correctly.  It is fairly straight-forward to revert to using `vsnprintf()`; it is not possible to use `snprintf()` or `sprintf()` reliably, I think.

Compilation:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra va.c -o va
```

Result:

```
Moon 55
JOY 4 55
!!!Hello World!!!
```

Comment: You define `char db[50];` twice - do you need the earlier definition? I'll upvote your answer after you address this point satisfactorily.

Comment: @Blaisorblade: There is no need for the global variable `db`; it is unused. I simply forgot to delete it.  My only excuse is it was there in the original (which isn't much of an excuse) and it didn't do any harm (which is also not a good excuse, however accurate).